# How to count number of char between specific characters with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have string variables such as: "xxx_YYYY_zzz"
both x, y and z may change their value and number of chars hence I can have:
 1. xx_YYY_z
 2. xxxx_Y_zzzzzzzzz
 3. x_yy_zzz
 4. etc

For each string variable, I would like to count and store in another variable the number of x, y and z chars because in the end I want to be able to print only the relevant part such as :

1. z
2. zzzzzzzzz
3. zzz

(Hence i take all chars after the last underscore)

or

I take all chars between the 2 underscores

1. YYY
2. Y
3. yy

The only thing which stay the same is the number of underscores. I always have: string_string_string 
Thank you

Comment: use `Dim arr As variant` and `arr=Split("xxx_YYYY_zzz","_")` and then loop through `arr` elements and count their length with `Len()` function

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Thank you DIsplayName, exactly what i was looking for. NEver heard about split befoe, very useful

Comment: you are welcome